# How to get the JSON array values without have JSON object values in android? Is it Possible?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

How to convert following type Json array in "tags_name": ["Activity Based"] in android and store data using getter setter methods.How to create POJO class, and how to handle when array is empty.I am struck with this concept.I  tried this following way. Please guide me to resolve this issue.

API

```
"postlist": [
              {
                "posts": {
                  "pm_post_id": "4647",
                },
                "tags_name": [
                  "Activity Based"
                ],
                "images_count": 0,
                "images": [],
                "post_user": [
                  {
                    "first_name": "Michelle",
                    "last_name": "Smith",
                    "profile_pic": "profess_sw_engg.jpg"
                  }
                ],
                "is_encourage_user": true,
                "encourage_feed_id": "992"
              },
              {
                "posts": {
                 "pm_post_id": "4647",
                },
                "tags_name": [],
                "images_count": 2,
                "images": [
                  {
                    "gallery_id": "5549",
                    "name": "IMG_20161012_1832491.jpg",

                  },
                  {
                    "gallery_id": "5550",
                    "name": "IMG_20161012_1832441.jpg",

                  }
                ],
                "post_user": [
                  {
                    "first_name": "Michelle",
                    "last_name": "Smith",
                    "profile_pic": "profess_sw_engg.jpg"
                  }
                ],
                "is_encourage_user": true,
                "encourage_feed_id": "993"
              }
    ]
```

In Java i've use Following code.

```
try {
                JSONArray tagNameArr = tempPostObject.getJSONArray("tags_name");
                for(int iloop=0;i<tagNameArr.length();iloop++)
                {
                    String street = tagNameArr.getString(iloop);
                    Log.i("..........",""+street);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: you should be able to use `gson` (https://github.com/google/gson) to do this

Comment: provide your JSON

Comment: i will  add it to question Mr.Arpit

Comment: Your question is not clear you are getting array with value and without value ,so how would it produce a NPE. ? .You can check for it's length right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this to get value of tags_name JSONArray.

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray tagName= jsonResponse.getJSONArray("tags_name");
for(int j=0;j<tagName.length();j++){
    temp.add(tagName.getString(j));
}
```

Comment: how it will pass to setter method?

Comment: @MohanRajS temp is a array list so according to position of arraylist you can set it in your setter.

Comment: Thank you so much bro. i got cleared the issue. perfectly working

Comment: if my question valid means give some credit, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Use jsonschema2pojo.org service and Gson converter (lib from Google). select Gson converter on the site.

Comment: i faced issue in gson seralization, when my array is empty it will create the null pointer exception, so i fallback to old method.

Comment: Now i updated API with my question, please give some suggestion bro, i was helpless. Thank your valuable time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use gson

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
RestaurantLoginResponseClass restaurantLoginResponse = gson.fromJson(loginResponseJsonString, RestaurantLoginResponseClass.class);
```

Add dependencies in app.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

Comment: i faced issue in gson seralization, when my array is empty it will create the null pointer exception, so i fallback to old method.

Comment: You can check array length or check whether object is null or not

Answer (score 2):

@MohanRaj , why you would to parse it ! , it is not clear , if you would to get the values and retain it in java object or save it in file system , you can use :

Gs

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Staff obj = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Staff.class);
```

if you have a list of object inside your json

you can create a list in your staff class something like :

```
@SerializedName("hits")
private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

GSON can understood it and parse the incoming list to those object .

you can get POJO from familiar JSON to java POJO tools : 
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
and you can check for more info https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide
http://www.java2blog.com/2013/11/gson-example-read-and-write-json.html

Comment: Mr.Ahemed some time my array might be empty, at that time serialisation will not help me yet. Throwing Null pointer exception.

Comment: Mohan , you mean in Json response itself ? , may be in sometimes not contain the array ?

Comment: Bro i have array with empty array value "tags_name": [ ] like this.

Comment: Mohan , if you using GSON , even if it is empty or null in json string , it will not throw null pointer exception .
you have something weird and you didn't clarify it well , which object throw NPE ?  
tempPostObject or tagNameArr !